# Al persistir la relación ManyToMany se realizan tantos updates como registros existen en la tabla relacionada

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Tengo una relación `ManyToMany` entra la entidad `CustomReport` y `AccessLog` representada mediante un EntityType con las propiedades multiple y expanded a true; la cuestión es que al hacer el `$em->persist($customReport);`, se almacena correctamente la relación en la tabla resultante (`custom_report_access_log`), pero se realizan tantos update sobre uno de los campos de la entidad AccessLog, como registros existan en la base de datos. Si cambio la propiedad expanded a false en el widget del formulario, entonces la cantidad de updates se realiza en proporción a la cantidad de opciones seleccionadas por el usuario en widget.

Denotar que no existe ningún lifecycle event ni nada similar sobre la entidad AccessLog o alguno de sus campos, y mucho menos sobre el campo ´consumo´ que sobre el que aparecen los updates que no deberían realizarse.

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CustomReportRepository::class)]
class CustomReport {

    use EntitySimpleAuditTrait;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[Assert\Valid]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'customReportsCollection')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Usuario $usuario = null;

    #[Assert\Length(max: 100, maxMessage: 'Máximo {{limit}} caracteres')]
    #[Assert\NotNull(message: 'Este campo es obligatorio.')]
    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $nombre = null;

    #[Assert\Length(max: 255, maxMessage: 'Máximo {{limit}} caracteres')]
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $descripcion = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'customReport', targetEntity: FilterGroup::class, orphanRemoval: true, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private Collection $filtersGroupsCollection;

    #[Assert\Type(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, message: 'El valor {{ value }} no es válido.')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $startDate = null;

    #[Assert\Type(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, message: 'El valor {{ value }} no es válido.')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $endDate = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: AccessLog::class, fetch: 'EXTRA_LAZY')]
    #[ORM\OrderBy(['fecha' => 'ASC'])]
    private Collection $accessLogsRelacionados;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'id_publico', type: 'uuid', nullable: false)]
    #[Assert\Uuid(versions: [UuidValidatorType::V4_RANDOM])]
    private UuidInterface|string|null $idPublico = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->idPublico = Uuid::uuid4();
        $this->filtersGroupsCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->accessLogsRelacionados = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsuario(): ?Usuario {
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    public function setUsuario(?Usuario $usuario): static {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(?string $nombre): static {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescripcion(): ?string {
        return $this->descripcion;
    }

    public function setDescripcion(?string $descripcion): static {
        $this->descripcion = $descripcion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, FilterGroup>
     */
    public function getFiltersGroupsCollection(): Collection {
        return $this->filtersGroupsCollection;
    }

    public function addFiltersGroupsCollection(FilterGroup $filtersGroup): static {
        if (!$this->filtersGroupsCollection->contains($filtersGroup)) {
            $this->filtersGroupsCollection->add($filtersGroup);
            $filtersGroup->setCustomReport($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFiltersGroupsCollection(FilterGroup $filtersGroup): static {
        if ($this->filtersGroupsCollection->removeElement($filtersGroup)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($filtersGroup->getCustomReport() === $this) {
                $filtersGroup->setCustomReport(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStartDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface {
        return $this->startDate;
    }

    public function setStartDate(?\DateTimeInterface $startDate): static {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEndDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface {
        return $this->endDate;
    }

    public function setEndDate(?\DateTimeInterface $endDate): static {
        $this->endDate = $endDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, AccessLog>
     */
    public function getAccessLogsRelacionados(): Collection {
        return $this->accessLogsRelacionados;
    }

    public function getAccessLogsRelacionadosAsStringChain(): ?string {
        return trim(implode(", ", $this->accessLogsRelacionados->toArray()), "\,");
    }

    public function addAccessLogsRelacionado(AccessLog $accessLogsRelacionado): static {
        if (!$this->accessLogsRelacionados->contains($accessLogsRelacionado)) {
            $this->accessLogsRelacionados->add($accessLogsRelacionado);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAccessLogsRelacionado(AccessLog $accessLogsRelacionado): static {
        $this->accessLogsRelacionados->removeElement($accessLogsRelacionado);

        return $this;
    }

    public function setAccessLogsRelacionado(ArrayCollection $accessLogsRelacionados): static {
        $this->accessLogsRelacionados = $accessLogsRelacionados;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setIdPublico(UuidInterface|string|null $idPublico): self {
        $this->idPublico = $idPublico;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdPublico(): UuidInterface|string|null {
        return $this->idPublico;
    }

}


#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AccessLogRepository::class)]
class AccessLog {

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $fecha = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $numeroDeFilasProcesadas = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $cantidadDeClientes;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'consumo', type: Types::BIGINT, nullable: false)]
    private ?int $consumo;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'porciento_cache', type: Types::DECIMAL, precision: 15, scale: 12, nullable: false)]
    private $porcientoCache = 0;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $nombre = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true, type: Types::JSON)]
    private array $archivosOrigen = [];

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $periodoIni = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $periodoFin = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: AccessLogTipo::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'tipo_id', referencedColumnName: 'id', nullable: true, onDelete: 'RESTRICT')]
    private ?AccessLogTipo $tipo = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: false)]
    private ?bool $archivoVacio = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: false)]
    private ?bool $archivoFinalizado = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->numeroDeFilasProcesadas = 0;
        $this->archivoVacio = false;
        $this->archivoFinalizado = false;
        $this->consumo = 0;
        $this->cantidadDeClientes = 0;
        $this->porcientoCache = 0;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFecha(): ?\DateTimeInterface {
        return $this->fecha;
    }

    public function setFecha(\DateTimeInterface $fecha): self {
        $this->fecha = $fecha;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNumeroDeFilasProcesadas(): ?int {
        return $this->numeroDeFilasProcesadas;
    }

    public function setNumeroDeFilasProcesadas(int $numeroDeFilasProcesadas): self {
        $this->numeroDeFilasProcesadas = $numeroDeFilasProcesadas;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCantidadDeClientes(): ?int {
        return $this->cantidadDeClientes;
    }

    public function setCantidaDeClientes(?int $cantidadDeClientes): self {
        $this->cantidadDeClientes = $cantidadDeClientes;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getConsumo(): int {
        return $this->consumo;
    }

    public function setConsumo(int $consumo): self {
        $this->consumo = $consumo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPorcientoCache(): ?string {
        return $this->porcientoCache;
    }

    public function setPorcientoCache(string $porcientoCache): self {
        $this->porcientoCache = $porcientoCache;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(?string $nombre): self {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getArchivosOrigen(): array {
        return $this->archivosOrigen;
    }

    public function setArchivosOrigen(?array $archivosOrigen): self {
        $this->archivosOrigen = $archivosOrigen;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPeriodoIni(): ?\DateTimeInterface {
        return $this->periodoIni;
    }

    public function setPeriodoIni(?\DateTimeInterface $periodoIni): self {
        $this->periodoIni = $periodoIni;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPeriodoFin(): ?\DateTimeInterface {
        return $this->periodoFin;
    }

    public function setPeriodoFin(?\DateTimeInterface $periodoFin): self {
        $this->periodoFin = $periodoFin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTipo(): ?AccessLogTipo {
        return $this->tipo;
    }

    public function setTipo(?AccessLogTipo $tipo): self {
        $this->tipo = $tipo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setCantidadDeClientes(int $cantidadDeClientes): self {
        $this->cantidadDeClientes = $cantidadDeClientes;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isArchivoVacio(): ?bool {
        return $this->archivoVacio;
    }

    public function setArchivoVacio(?bool $archivoVacio): self {
        $this->archivoVacio = $archivoVacio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isArchivoFinalizado(): ?bool {
        return $this->archivoFinalizado;
    }

    public function setArchivoFinalizado(?bool $archivoFinalizado): self {
        $this->archivoFinalizado = $archivoFinalizado;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Entidad AccessLog:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AccessLogRepository::class)]
class AccessLog {

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $fecha = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $numeroDeFilasProcesadas = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $cantidadDeClientes;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'consumo', type: Types::BIGINT, nullable: false)]
    private ?int $consumo;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'porciento_cache', type: Types::DECIMAL, precision: 15, scale: 12, nullable: false)]
    private $porcientoCache = 0;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $nombre = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true, type: Types::JSON)]
    private array $archivosOrigen = [];

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $periodoIni = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $periodoFin = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: AccessLogTipo::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'tipo_id', referencedColumnName: 'id', nullable: true, onDelete: 'RESTRICT')]
    private ?AccessLogTipo $tipo = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: false)]
    private ?bool $archivoVacio = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: false)]
    private ?bool $archivoFinalizado = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->numeroDeFilasProcesadas = 0;
        $this->archivoVacio = false;
        $this->archivoFinalizado = false;
        $this->consumo = 0;
        $this->cantidadDeClientes = 0;
        $this->porcientoCache = 0;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFecha(): ?\DateTimeInterface {
        return $this->fecha;
    }

    public function setFecha(\DateTimeInterface $fecha): self {
        $this->fecha = $fecha;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNumeroDeFilasProcesadas(): ?int {
        return $this->numeroDeFilasProcesadas;
    }

    public function setNumeroDeFilasProcesadas(int $numeroDeFilasProcesadas): self {
        $this->numeroDeFilasProcesadas = $numeroDeFilasProcesadas;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCantidadDeClientes(): ?int {
        return $this->cantidadDeClientes;
    }

    public function setCantidaDeClientes(?int $cantidadDeClientes): self {
        $this->cantidadDeClientes = $cantidadDeClientes;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getConsumo(): int {
        return $this->consumo;
    }

    public function setConsumo(int $consumo): self {
        $this->consumo = $consumo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPorcientoCache(): ?string {
        return $this->porcientoCache;
    }

    public function setPorcientoCache(string $porcientoCache): self {
        $this->porcientoCache = $porcientoCache;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(?string $nombre): self {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getArchivosOrigen(): array {
        return $this->archivosOrigen;
    }

    public function setArchivosOrigen(?array $archivosOrigen): self {
        $this->archivosOrigen = $archivosOrigen;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPeriodoIni(): ?\DateTimeInterface {
        return $this->periodoIni;
    }

    public function setPeriodoIni(?\DateTimeInterface $periodoIni): self {
        $this->periodoIni = $periodoIni;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPeriodoFin(): ?\DateTimeInterface {
        return $this->periodoFin;
    }

    public function setPeriodoFin(?\DateTimeInterface $periodoFin): self {
        $this->periodoFin = $periodoFin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTipo(): ?AccessLogTipo {
        return $this->tipo;
    }

    public function setTipo(?AccessLogTipo $tipo): self {
        $this->tipo = $tipo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setCantidadDeClientes(int $cantidadDeClientes): self {
        $this->cantidadDeClientes = $cantidadDeClientes;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isArchivoVacio(): ?bool {
        return $this->archivoVacio;
    }

    public function setArchivoVacio(?bool $archivoVacio): self {
        $this->archivoVacio = $archivoVacio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isArchivoFinalizado(): ?bool {
        return $this->archivoFinalizado;
    }

    public function setArchivoFinalizado(?bool $archivoFinalizado): self {
        $this->archivoFinalizado = $archivoFinalizado;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Clase del formulario CustomReportType:

```
class CustomReportType extends AbstractType {

    public function __construct(private readonly ManagerRegistry $manager) {
        
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void {
        $builder
                ->add('nombre', TextType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Nombre del reporte',
                    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'text-secondary']
                ])
                ->add('descripcion', TextareaType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Descripción',
                    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'text-secondary']
                ])
                ->add('accessLogsRelacionados', EntityType::class, [
                    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'text-secondary text-bold'],
                    'class' => AccessLog::class,
                    'query_builder' => function () {
                        return $this->manager->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
                        ->select('al')
                        ->from(AccessLog::class, 'al')
                        ->orderBy('al.fecha', 'DESC');
                    },
                    'choice_label' => function (AccessLog $entity) {
                        return $entity->getNombre();
                    },
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'required' => true,
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'iCheck-source']
                ])
                ->add('filtersGroupsCollection', CollectionType::class, [
                    'label' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'entry_type' => FilterGroupType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'delete_empty' => true,
                    'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'prototype_name' => '__filterGroups__'
                ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => CustomReport::class,
        ]);
    }

}
```

Action controller:

```
#[Route('/new', name: 'nuevo')]
    public function new(Request $request): Response {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            try {

                $em = $this->manager->getManager();

                $customReport = new CustomReport();
                $customReport->setUsuario($this->security->getUser());

                $initialGroup = new FilterGroup();
                $initialFilterInIntialGroup = new Filter();
                $initialGroup->addFiltersCollection($initialFilterInIntialGroup);

                $customReport->addFiltersGroupsCollection($initialGroup);

                $customReportForm = $this->createForm(CustomReportType::class, $customReport, [
                    'action' => $this->generateUrl('app_reportesPersonalizados_nuevo')
                ]);

                if ($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)) {
                    $customReportForm->handleRequest($request);

                    if ($customReportForm->isSubmitted() && $customReportForm->isValid()) {
                        if ($customReport->getAccessLogsRelacionados()->isEmpty()) {
                            return new Response("Seleccione al menos un registro de log para analizar.", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
                        }

                        $firstAccessLog = $customReport->getAccessLogsRelacionados()->last();
                        $lastAccessLog = $customReport->getAccessLogsRelacionados()->first();

                        $customReport->setStartDate($firstAccessLog->getPeriodoIni());
                        $customReport->setEndDate($lastAccessLog->getPeriodoFin());
                        $em->persist($customReport);

                        $em->flush();

                        return new Response("Filtro configurado satisfactoriamente");
                    } else {
                        return new Response($this->renderView('reporte_personalizado/customReportForm.html.twig', ['form' => $customReportForm->createView()]), Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
                    }
                }

                return $this->render('reporte_personalizado/customReportForm.html.twig', ['form' => $customReportForm->createView()]);
            } catch (Exception $exc) {
                $this->logger->error(sprintf("[%s:%s]: %s", self::class, __FUNCTION__, $exc->getMessage()));
                return new Response($exc->getMessage(), Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        } else {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException("Recurso no encontrado");
        }
    }
```

Logger resultante, nótese la cantidad de sentencias `UPDATE access_log SET consumo = ? WHERE id = ? (parameters: array{"1":**valor-consumo-actual**,"2":**id-del-registro**}...` que se realizan, una por cada registro existente en `access_log`, la imagen solo muestra unos pocos para sintentizar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]